# Failing to update state based on prevState

Tags: reactjs

I need to update state to initial value if current state is not equal to previous state.

This is my state:

```
  const [selectType, setType] = useState("");
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

This is my Custom Hook to get the previous state:

```
  const usePrevious = (value) => {
    const ref = useRef();
    useEffect(() => {
      ref.current = value;
    }, [value]);
    return ref.current;
  };



const prevSelectType = usePrevious(selectType);
```

This is how I am fetching data and trying to set state to initial value conditionally:

```
  const getCategory = async (type) => {
    setType(type);
    if (selectType !== prevSelectType) {
      setData([]);
    }
    const result = await getData(type.toLowerCase());
    setData(result.data);
  };
```

My problem is that "prevSelectType" is turning to "selectType" after some couple of seconds and
I can't set state to initial value based on this condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I see couple of fixes here

1. No need of custom hook to get the previous state it can be received via

   setState((prevState) => ({
   if(prevState !== state)
   }));
2. State is not sync

> setType(type); // getting the value after immediately updating the
> state doesn't get the updated state.
> The following should be changed to

```
    if (type !== selectType) { // since selectType will have the previous selectType value 
      setData([]); 
    }
```

Comment: what mean > and this > in here ?  > if(prevState !== state) >

Comment: and setState you mean setType in my case?

Comment: yeah check the edited answer setState refers to your state